# Will Codename one application work with Appium?

Tags: appium, codenameone

I have a Codename One application and I want to test it with Appium. Is that possible or I must use Codename One's test recorder? I want to test my application on actual devices using Sauce Labs + Appium, but Appium is Selenium based, so I am not sure whether it will work, since Codename One uses specific components, different from the native Andoid /iOS components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have support for building automated tests for devices in the enterprise subscription tier although at the moment this doesn't work with any device farms.

Comment: codename one uses java for building apps so selenium should work, correct me if am wrong ?

Comment: Updated server farms to device farms which is what I meant. @iltafkhalid no. We have our own testing framework which is better suited to the translation process. The problem is with on-device-automation which is non-trivial

Comment: Thanks @shai. I have written a java application using selenium for automated testing. I am now working on to develop similar android and iOs apps for automated testing. Currently I am only wondering where to start with regarding choice of cross-platform frameworks like titanium, codename one and xamarin.

Comment: You can automate testing on the Codename One simulator, we have a test recorder and our own test framework. Automating the tests to a device is a bit more complicated. We have a partial solution for enterprise users